# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 4 when trying to add to cart

Tags: flutter, api, dart, bloc, flutter-cubit

```
 ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
        onPressed: () {
            cubit.addItemToCart(
                id: cubit.getCartModel!.data[index].id);
        },
        child: Text(LocaleKeys.addToCart.tr()),
 )
```

I'm trying to add item to cart so this RangeError Appears to me if anyone know how to solve it, I'll Aprreciate his Effort

Comment: If you also share your code for where the variable index comes from, we might be able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Your range error comes from this line

```
cubit.getCartModel!.data[index]
```

It tells you that `index` is

- larger than or equal to the number of elements in your list `cubit.getCartModel`
- or smaller than zero

This is a problem because you can only select list elements in a range from `0...length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this list is empty.

> cubit.getCartModel!.data

and you are accessing it with

> index=4

Comment: API  return 6 items in the list but first item only is the one which I can Add To cart the Other items return RangeError